# Is it possible to write node.js addons in go?

Tags: node.js, go

I guess it's all about whether libuv and the other c/cpp glue can be somehow imitated from within a go executable. Is it possible? If yes, could you provide some guidance on where to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible (read *very complicated*) to build shared objects with Go, as to dynamically link them into a system. It's for this same reason that Go can only interface with other web servers through CGI or Fast-CGI.

So my answer would be *not directly*. maybe you could achieve something through IPC and a small C-"proxy" that's linked into node.

Comment: That would be quite expensive though, wouldn't it? The whole point of writing modules in go would be to gain performance (wrt js, not c/cpp)

Comment: It depends; for small operations the IPC overhead would render Go's speed insignificant. For big stuff that Go's good at where as JS is not (e.g. concurrency), the cost of IPC could be justified.